# Possible to connect a amp and sub to a stock 2001 seat ibiza radio

Tags: audio, seat-ibiza, seat-cars

Yesterday i bought an amplifier and matching subwoofer (1200watts amp with dual 10" 800 watts subwoofer). Now i've been looking for a replacement dash panel for a seat ibiza for some time now and yesterday an offer passed my attention which i just couldn't pass. So i ended up buying the set. Now i'm wondering if it's at all possible to connect the sub and amp to my stock sound installation. If its not possible are there any workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of plugs in the back of the MK2 Seat Ibiza's radio that will easily allow you to connect it to your stock system. This will require some splicing of the wires, but definitely shouldn't be too difficult to manage. There is a power plug and a speaker plug. Make sure you're splicing into the correct one, or you could damage the system.

The power plug looks like:

[image: MK2 Seat Ibiza radio power plug]

The speaker plug looks like:

[image: MK2 Seat Ibiza radio speaker plug]

The schematics of these plugs should be:

[image: MK2 Seat Ibiza power plug and radio plug schematics]

With all of this information in hand, you should be able to perform the following steps.

1. Order a pair of http://www.crutchfield.com/p_136XDCLR2S/JL-Audio-XD-CLRAIC2-SW.html to splice into the speaker wires for your inputs. You could also cut your input wire and splice it in directly, but I typically choose to order these instead of cutting my input wires and having to buy a new set in the future for another vehicle.
2. Splice your inputs into the **speaker plug's** wiring, following the schematic:

   - Rear right positive: BRN/BLK
   - Rear right ground: GRN/RED
   - Rear left positive: BRN/RED
   - Rear left ground: GRN/BLUE
3. Run your amplifier remote to the **power plug's** ACC wire (GRN/BLUE). This will tell your amplifier that your car has been switched on, just as it does with the radio.
4. Run your power and ground from your amplifier. If you have enough ground wire to run directly to your battery, do that. If not, find somewhere close to your amp that would be a good ground. If it's painted, you'll need to get some sandpaper and get rid of the paint so that it makes a good connection.

After that, enjoy the new sound. You will probably have to tune your amplifier quite a bit to get rid of voices in the system, since this vehicle doesn't have a dedicated subwoofer output. Turning on the LPF (low pass filter) on the amp will usually take care of that.

Comment: Thanks for the VERY detailed answer! I will surely look into doing this.

Comment: No problem. Let me know if you need any more help. :)